# How to calculate multiple averages in one query in linq to entities

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

How to do this in linq to entities in one query?

```
SELECT avg(Column1), avg(Column2), ... from MyTable 
where ColumnX = 234
```

??

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
var averages = myTable
    .Where(item => item.ColumnX == 234)
    .Aggregate(
        new { count = 0, sum1 = 0.0, sum2 = 0.0 },
        (acc, item) => new { count = acc.count + 1, sum1 = acc.sum1 + item.Column1, sum2 = acc.sum2 + item.Column2 },
        acc => new { avg1 = acc.sum1 / acc.count, avg2 = acc.sum2 / acc.count });
```

<strike>Note the call to `AsEnumerable()` to force `Aggregate` to be executed locally (as EF probably doesn't know how to convert it to SQL)</strike> *Actually it seems to work ;)*

Alternatively, you could use this query:

```
var averages =
    from item in table
    where item.ColumnX == 234
    group item by 1 into g
    select new
    {
        Average1 = g.Average(i => i.Column1),
        Average2 = g.Average(i => i.Column2)
    };
```

The use of `group by` here is not very intuitive, but it's probably easier to read than the other solution. Not sure it can be converted to SQL though...